# Can't find the SysMl Toolbox in Enterprise Architect

Tags: requirements, system-requirements, sysml

I'm trying to make a requirement diagram, but I can't find the SysML Toolbox. Following the Sparxsystems help pages I tried to add the SysML Toolbox by clicking the `More tools...` button in the toolbox tab,  but there is no SysML menu. 
I'm using the `EA Academic Version 10.0.1009`. 
Does anybody know how can I model SysML requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase the *SysML MDG technology for EA* first:
http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/tech/sysml/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you purchase the ultimate edition or if you have the [specific MDG technology installed.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/tech/sysml/index.html)